# How to subset element of list with columns which contain only value==3?

Tags: r, list

```
>List
 [[1]]         col1    col2
  2013-07-17   0.150    1
  2013-08-14   0.150    1
  2013-09-18   0.150    1
 [[1]]         col1    col2
  2013-07-17   0.150    1
  2013-08-17   0.150    1
  2013-09-17   0.150    1
 [[1]]         col1    col2
  2013-07-17   0.150    3
  2013-08-17   0.150    3
  2013-09-17   0.150    1
```

How to extract only the element of list which contain only the column with value=3. The output should be this:

```
   >List
  [[1]]        col1   col2
  2013-07-17   0.150    3
  2013-08-17   0.150    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lapply` with `subset`

```
output <- lapply(List, subset, col2 == 3)
```

---

If you prefer `tidyverse`, this can be done with

```
purrr::map(List, dplyr::filter, col2 == 3)
```